# apache and cgicc - differentiate between post and get variables

Tags: c++, apache

In PHP it is very simple to check, if a variable has been transmitted via `GET` or `POST`. With the cgicc library they all look the same. Is there another possibility to read only `GET` or only `POST` variables?

My Code:

```
cgicc:Cgicc cgiobj;
std::cout << "Both, post or get: " << cgiobj("variablename") << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same question so I looked for a solution in the cgicc documentation.
Class **CgiEnvironment** provides getRequestMethod() which returns "GET" or "POST" accordingly to your request.

eg.

```
cgicc::Cgicc cgi;
cgicc::CgiEnvironment env = cgi.getEnvironment();
std::string requestMethod = env.getRequestMethod();
```

I have not tested it, though.